# directory string in python not working

Tags: python

I am looking to set a directory path to source string but I am getting back an odd result.

Firstly, this works fine

```
 source = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Py"
 os.listdir(source)
```

and lists:

```
['python vocab - files.txt', 'test destination folder', 'test source folder']
```

but if I want to drill in an additional level I get an error

```
source = "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Py\test destination folder"
 os.listdir(source)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    mylist = os.listdir(source)
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Py\test destination folder/*.*'`
```

Comment: Maybe the space causes problems?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not escaping your backslashes. In the directory, you see `'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Py\test destination folder`, where `'\\'` is just one backslash and `'\t'` is a tab.
Correct this to a raw string, `r'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Py\test destination folder\*.*'` or just escaping the backslashes (`'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Py\\test destination folder\\*.*'`)

Comment: Note that `\U`, `\O`, `\D` and `\P`aren't escape characters, so this wasn't a problem with the previous path as Python just left those as backslashes.